# What is the correct pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

Today, I talked with my friend. And we both have different opinion to each other. The subject is

Does **British** English (native) speaker pronunce the R letter at end of the word.

You only think the case of pronunce any word ending with R.

Please, answer. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on ***which dialect of British English***. Some, yes; the most common ones, no. (And it's the reverse in the U.S.)

Comment: I surprised that some speak American English does not pronunce the word ending letter R.

Comment: Anyway, In the case of England or more specific, in London.

Comment: For example, in Boston, Massachusetts (US), the "r" in car is not pronounced so that it sounds like "cah".  That is the most striking example I can think of in AmE.

Answer (score 1):

It's less obvious than in AmE, but it's there in some situations, see in [this British Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/car),where the "r" in the British pronunciation is **raised**.

Also:

> Trends in phonological theory until 1975: a historical ... - Page 131
>   Eli Fischer-Jørgensen - 1995
>
> **An example of latency is final r in British English, e.g. in jar [fa:]**. Before a vow'el there is no latency, e.g. 1n far away ['far
>   a'wei], but /r/ is latent elsewhere. A latent consonant is also
>   assumed to exist in the genitive plural of most English nouns; ...

Also, see **"floating consonant"** in

> [A Glossary of Phonology](https://books.google.ca/books?id=_rS22ow4stUC&pg=PA55&dq=latency%20and%20%20%22final%20r%22%20english&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5z4kVbrRN4WhyAS6l4CQBQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=latency%20and%20%20%22final%20r%22%20english&f=false)  By Philip Carr
>
> **floating consonants** Also
>   known as latent consonants, these are usually **word-final** consonants
>   which are not realized unless they can occupy the **onset** position in the following word

Also, see [this](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/65010523) and [this](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/173107182). The latter shows a comparative recording.